Non-zero resitivity in perfect crystal
It is very commonly stated that a perfect crystal has zero resistivity at zero temperature due to its translation invariance. However, in Critical drag as a mechanism for resistivity by Else and Senthil, they state that this is only the case if one has continuous translation invariance (excluding the more complicated mechanisms). They state:

Thus, we have reproduced a well-known fact: systems with momentum conservation, and nonzero electric charge density, generally can carry dissipationless electric
current. On the other hand, in condensed matter physics we are generally interested in systems on the lattice that do not have such a conservation law. Note that
conservation of lattice momentum (as opposed to continuous momentum) is not sufficient on its own to obtain dissipationless electric current, as current can degrade
by Umklapp scattering.

I would like to know if someone has a proof for this or a reference to such a proof.
I summarize the extent of my understanding below:
So crystal momentum is different from the typical momentum we consider in continuous systems. It is defined up to modulo up to a multiple of the reciprocal lattice vector, meaning it's periodic in the Brillouin zone. So now the statement is that Umklapp scattering leads to resistivity in that it conserved crystal momentum but not momentum in that some momentum is transfer to the lattice.
Umklapp scattering is the process when the total crystal momentum of electrons changes by a reciprocal lattice vector $G$. In a scattering event involving two electrons with momenta $k_1$ and $k_2$, the final momenta $k_1'$ and $k_2'$ satisfy:
$k_1' + k_2' = k_1 + k_2 + G$
Here, crystal momentum is conserved modulo a reciprocal lattice vector $G$. When the total momentum exceeds the first Brillouin zone, it is "folded" back by subtracting $G$, leading to an Umklapp process.
Physically, Umklapp scattering transfers momentum to the lattice, contributing to electrical resistivity as momentum is no longer conserved within the electron system alone. This occurs because crystal momentum is only defined up to $G$.
I, however, do not understand why a perturbatively small potential difference would lead to such a process at zero temperature.
